# Print if something is printed in the console

Tags: python, printing, timer

I would like to monitor the progress of a given Python function (for those that know it, `GridSearchCV` from machine learning package Scikit Learn) during its execution. To do so, given the function has a parameter `verbose`, I can set the verbosity to be 1 or 10, whatever. However, I would also like to have some kind of time monitoring. The idea I had was **to print on the console a timer each time something is printed in the console** (in this case, printings would come from the activation of the verbosity of `GridSearchCV`), let's call this the `printing function`.

My questions are the following:

- Is there a way in Python to execute a program when something is printed in the console?
- A difficulty I see here is that, when I execute all these instructions (function `GridSearchCV`, the `printing function`), I am afraid what will happen is that `GridSearchCV` will be executed entirely, and then all the timers will be printed at the end. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Check whether `GridSearchCV()` provides a proper progress API (e.g., whether it accepts a callback that is called periodically (such as [`reporthook` in urlretrieve()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve)) or whether it prints progress info to a socket, pipe that you can provide).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by redirecting `sys.stdout` to your own custom class that can add information into the output. Here is an example of how that could be achieved. I pass in a datetime object to use as the reference to compute how much time has elapsed. Then when anything is printed to stdout, `CustomStdout.write()` is called and I then evaluate how much time has elapsed since the reference time and insert that information into the text being displayed, then display it using the initial stdout.

```
import sys
import time

from datetime import datetime


class CustomStdout():
    def __init__(self, start_time=None):
        self.stdout = sys.stdout
        self.start_time = start_time or datetime.now()

    def write(self, text):
        elapsed = datetime.now() - self.start_time

        text = text.rstrip()
        if len(text) == 0:
            return

        elapsed_str = '[%d.%03d seconds]' % (elapsed.seconds, elapsed.microseconds / 1000.)
        self.stdout.write('%s %s\n' % (elapsed_str, text))


print 'Printing before stdout redirect'

# Redirect stdout
sys.stdout = CustomStdout()

print 'Stdout now redirected'
print 'About to sleep 5 seconds'
time.sleep(5)
print 'Slept 5 seconds'
```

The output is

```
Printing before stdout redirect
[0.000 seconds] Stdout now redirected
[0.000 seconds] About to sleep 5 seconds
[5.004 seconds] Slept 5 seconds
```

Comment: it won't work if `GridSearchV()` uses [C stdout or prints at a file descriptor level (e.g., if it spawns subprocesses)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279)